# php class is not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

why my code is not working here I think I made something wrong but I just can not determine it if anyone can spot what I have made wrong here I will be thankfull

here is my code: I am trying here to use php class to insert new row in the database

```
<?php
$connection = new PDO('mysql:dbname=master;host=localhost','root','123');
/*if($connection)
{
    echo 'Database is connected successfully';
}
else
     {
    echo 'please connect to a database';
}*/
class Topics
{
    public $id;
    public $title;
    public $body;
    public static $table_name = 'topics';
    public static $fields = array ('title','body');
    private function attributes()
    {
        $string = array();  
        foreach (self::$fields as $field) 
        {
            if (!empty($field)) {
                if(is_int($this->$field))
                {
                    $string[] = $field." =".$this->$field;
                }
                else
                {
                    $string[] = $field." ="."'".$this->$field."'";
                }

            }   

        }
        return join(',', $string);
    }
    public function add()
    {
        global $connection;
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO'.self::$table_name.'SET'.$this->attributes();
        $number_of_affected_rows = $connection->exec($sql);
        if($number_of_affected_rows >0)
        {
            $this->id = $connection->lastInsertId();
        }
        return ($number_of_affected_rows>0) ? $number_of_affected_rows : FALSE;
    }
}
$mohamed = new Topics();
$mohamed->title = 'Hello';
$mohamed->body = 'Hello world again';
return $mohamed->add();
?>
```

Comment: What behavior were you expecting, and what were you seeing instead? Are there any errors or notices being output? Do you have [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) enabled?

Comment: "not working" is a very broad description. Can you be a little more explicit about what the problem is.

Comment: You're using PDO already, which is good, but you're not escaping your data. PDO provides a function specially for this -- rather than `."'".$this->$field."'"`, use `PDO::Quote($this->$field)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's not working exactly? Your SQL is wrong anyway, beacause it needs whitespaces in it.

`'INSERT INTO '.self::$table_name.' SET '.$this->attributes();`

And btw you should also escape table and field name in your SQL.

Comment: Thank you for the help I was expecting something dump but I did not thought it will be that dump